# De onde surgiu a expressão "vice-versa"?

Tags: etimologia

Geralmente usamos essa expressão pra indicar o inverso de algo dito anteriormente.

Quando e por que surgiu essa expressão?

[Segundo o Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=vice-versa)

#### Vice-versa

> **1**. em ordem invertida à ordem inicialmente dada; em sentido inverso.
>   *"é necessário que quem está em cima desça, e vice-versa"*
>
> **2**. de modo recíproco ou mútuo.
>   *"eu esfrego tuas costas, e vice-versa"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Vice-versa* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/vice-versa) é uma locução latina que literalmente significa ‘às avessas’ (Aulete), ‘sendo a ordem invertida’ (minha tradução do [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vice-versa)) ou ‘sendo o lugar ou a vez invertidos’ (minha tradução do [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/vice-versa)). Está atestada em francês em 1418 (CNRTL) e em inglês cerca de 1600. A ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei em português é de 1625, em [Gaspar Pires Rebelo, *Infortúnios Trágicos de Constante Florinda* ([Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp); descobri a data da publicação [aqui](http://www.ufjf.br/darandina/files/2010/01/resenha01.pdf); ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> E como eu não andava corrente em negócios de amor, que me pareceu que ele era o que minha ama não amava e o outro com quem já falara uma noite, queria; mas que estivesse certo que tudo era **vice-versa**, isto é, que ele era o estimado e o outro aborrecido.

Neste caso, *vice-versa* parece signifcar simplesmente o contrário. O exemplo seguinte, que já está de acordo com o uso atual, é de 1642, n’*Methodo de Conhecer e Tratar o Morbo Gallico* de Duarte Madeira (indicação do Houaiss), citado no [*Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* de Raphael Bluteau de 1721](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ScVKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA472&lpg=PA472&dq=viceversa.%20Madeira%20de%20Morbo&source=bl&ots=Uz2I4xC4FZ&sig=cgR1nBGWVRC4wuc5cJV4PAT0xrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP-cawqtHRAhUDOhQKHS8VDmgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=viceversa.%20Madeira%20de%20Morbo&f=false), cujo o verbete transcrevo na íntegra (grafia original):

> **Vice versa**. Saõ dicçoens Latinas, de que às vezes usamos fallando Portuguez, & valem o mesmo que *Pelo contrario*. (Muitas vezes do contagio das bexigas nasce sarampaõ, & **viceversa**. Madeira de Morbo Gall.part.2.pag.17.)

Answer (score 4):

**Expressão de origem Latina, "vice-versa" é usada não só em Português mas em muitas outras línguas (Francês, Inglês, Espanhol, etc) e significa "a posição foi invertida" ou "invertendo-se a ordem".** É formada por "vice" (ablativo de "vicis") que significa "alternação, troca, ordem alternada + "versa" (ablativo feminino singular de "versus") particípio passado de "vertere" que significa "inverter, transformar".

> - [**vice versa**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vice+versa) - Look up vice versa at Dictionary.com
>     "the order being changed," c. 1600, Latin, from vice, ablative of vicis "a change, alternation, alternate order" (see vicarious) + versa, feminine ablative singular of versus, past participle of vertere "to turn, turn about" (see versus). "The phrase has the complete force of a proposition, being as much as to say that upon a transposition of antecedents the consequents are also transposed" [Century Dictionary].

Em Inglês e em Francês frequentemente encontramos "vice-versa" precedida de "et" ("et vice-versa").

Comment: boa informação de Centaurus!Sem desfazer de Jacinto. Mais completa.