# O que significa 'vice-versa' diferente de 'vide verso'?

Tags: expressões

Qual é a função da expressão 'vice-versa', detalhadamente o significado de 'vice' e de 'versa'?

Qual é a diferença de 'vice' em 'vice-versa', e 'vide' em 'vide verso'?

Comment: Além de _vice_ não ser a mesma coisa de _vide_, como mencionado na pergunta, _versa_ não é a mesma coisa de _verso_. Na verdade, acho que não é nem possível separar _vice_ e _versa_, mas talvez alguém me prove errado em uma resposta.

Comment: Renanlinus, não achei *vide-verso* em nenhum dicionário. Podes dizer onde achaste *vide-verso*? Se não o souberes, qual é o seu significado?

Comment: @RafaelTavares, *vice-versa* é uma locução latina. O genitivo de *vicis* (ordem, condição) + o adjetivo *versa* (inverso, invertido, ao contrário). ou seja, *vice-versa* é *de ordem inversa*, que, no português, funciona como um advérbio. Agora, se *vide verso* é latim, *vide* é *vê/veja(-se)* e *verso*, nesse caso, é inversamente ou de modo inverso, então, seria traduzido literalmente como *veja-se inversamente*, o que, tanto em português quanto em latim, pode ser figurativamente *entenda inversamente*. Mas não sei se *vide verso* é latim. Por sinal, meu latim não é dos melhores.

Comment: @Schilive ao ler a pergunta, interpretei _vide verso_ como algo similar a "conforme dito no verso (atrás)". Por exemplo: "Instruções de uso: vide verso" (este exemplo está no [dicionário informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/vide+verso/8109/))

Comment: @RafaelTavares, não confio no Dicionário Informal, mas também faz sentido em latim, eu acho. Outros sites outrossim o disseram.  Renanlinux, qual é a tua dúvida exatamente? não conseguir entender.

Comment: Pelo que entendo, (e já usei, não sei se com certeza, se sem), vide verso era para continuar lendo no outro lado de uma folha de papel, a continuação do escrito na parte frontal, o que também indicava para quem lesse a segunda primeiro, que essa não era a primeira, mas a parte traseira não indicava 'vide verso' informando que a frontal era a primeira. Daria para entender se houvesse um contexto claro que informasse o leitor de que a parte frontal era realmente a primeira, mas geralmente escrevemos 'vide verso' na parte frontal, o que o leitor sabendo entenderia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Vide verso*** é uma mistura de latim e português, e é usado com o significado ’veja o verso, o outro lado’ (de uma folha num livro, por exemplo), como na revista [tpm (julho de 2003)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=42EEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT43&dq=%22vide%20verso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXp9muzIXzAhWmSPEDHU7vCjUQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22vide%20verso%22&f=false), neste [Routledge Portuguese Bilingual Dictionary (2014)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hhAcC7zwEdwC&pg=PA631&dq=%22vide%20verso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXp9muzIXzAhWmSPEDHU7vCjUQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22vide%20verso%22&f=false), ou ainda na canção [vide verso meu endereço de Adoniran Barbosa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVL4NFeXfzo) (1’35’’).

***Vide*** é latim, literalmente, ’vê’ (imperativo de *ver*). Citando o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/vide):

> *vide* |uídè| ou |vídè|²
> (palavra latina, segunda pessoa do singular do imperativo do verbo *vídeo, -ere*, ver)
> *verbo*
> Palavra usada para remeter para outro local do texto ou para outro texto (ex.: vide *gráfico anexo*)

[***Verso*** (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/verso), neste contexto, é naturalmente  ’outro lado da folha’.

***Vice-versa*** é tudo latim. Já há esta [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/de-onde-surgiu-a-express%C3%A3o-vice-versa) sobre este termo. Acrescento só que ***vice*** é o ablativo de [*vicis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vicis#Latin) (no latim, a terminação da palavra variava consoante a função), cujo o acusativo é *vicem*, que é a origem da palavra portuguesa *vez* (portanto não tem dada que ver com *vide*). ***Versa*** é o ablativo feminino de [*versus* (Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/versus#Latin), que significava ’voltado, invertido, que foi voltado’, etc. Portanto podes pensar em *vice-versa* como “vez invertida” (*eu ajudo-te a ti e vice-versa*). A palavra portuguesa *verso* é que já está relacionada com este *versa* do *vice-versa*. *Verso* vem do latim *versum*, que é o acusativo masculino do mesmo *versus*: o verso da folha é um bocado como aquilo que é voltado.